# Displaying data from an array using radio buttons gives me an [object object] value attribute

Tags: radio-button, svelte, bind

I'm very new to Svelte and am quite an amateur in JS in general.
I have a bit of code where I'm trying to bind the data from a radio button from an array to output on the UI.
Following code:

```
<script>
    let items = [
        { name: 'A', price: 10 },
        { name: 'B', price: 20 },
        { name: 'C', price: 30 }
    ];
    
    let selected = '';
</script>

{#each items as item}
    <label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            bind:group={selected}
            name={item.name}
            value={item}
        > {item.name}
    </label>
{/each}

<p>{selected.price}</p>
```

Everything works as intended for the UI, but the value attribute in the HTML is [object object].

If I change the value to {item.name} (which is what I'm after), the value attribute is correct, but I don't know how to then call the price, or any future additional items from the array as it then becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "the value attribute is correct"

If you see `[object object]` in the Html it's not that the value is wrong, just that the item itself is saved as value. You can see that by adding `$: console.log(selected)`

I'm not sure it's good practise to have a radio group without an option selected. I'd either start with one or add an option for 'no item'

> If I change the value to {item.name} (which is what I'm after)

When using the item itself as value, but the name is needed, it can be simply 'extracted' via a reactive variable `$: name = selected.name`

###### One option selected

```
<script>
    let items = [
        { name: 'A', price: 10 },
        { name: 'B', price: 20 },
        { name: 'C', price: 30 }
    ];

    let selected = items[0];
    $: name = selected.name
</script>

{#each items as item}
<label>
    <input
                 type="radio"
                 bind:group={selected}
                 name="items"
                 value={item}
                 > {item.name}
</label>
{/each}

<p>{selected.price}</p>
```

###### additional option

```
<script>
    let items = [
        { name: 'A', price: 10 },
        { name: 'B', price: 20 },
        { name: 'C', price: 30 }
    ];

    let selected = '';
    $: name = selected.name
</script>

<label>
    <input
                 type="radio"
                 bind:group={selected}
                 name="items"
                 value=""
                 > No item please
</label>
{#each items as item}
<label>
    <input
                 type="radio"
                 bind:group={selected}
                 name="items"
                 value={item}
                 > {item.name}
</label>
{/each}

<p>{selected.price ?? ''}</p>
```

Comment: (I suspected that this question has to do with form data, which relies on the value attribute. If not then simply binding the whole item object is great.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `value={item.name}`, `selected` will become the `name` of the selected item. That means that if you want to access the associated item, you first need to retrieve it from the `items`, e.g using [a reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive).

```js
let selected = '';
$: selectedItem = items.find(x => x.name == selected);
```

`selectedItem` can be `undefined`, so accessing it is not safe. Either use `selectedItem?.price` or some other guard mechanism like `{#if selectedItem}` when using it in the template.

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/d5f91354ea174e74b18acf4c684c4d54?version=3.49.0)